# Why there is an extra execution of setInterval's function if we change order of setTimeout and setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Why code 1 runs 9 times and code 2 runs 10 times. Both are async operations and both should run in a separate thread (in the background). But why 1 extra iteration for code 2. Does setTimeout and setInterval has priority or it just First come first serve execution?

**CODE 1** [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/poNoMvX?editors=1111)

```js
let isValid = true,
    counter = 0;

setTimeout(() => {
  isValid = false;
  clearInterval(id);
}, 2000);

const id = setInterval(() => {
  if (isValid) {
    console.log(counter++);
  }
}, 200);
```

**CODE 2** [codepen](https://codepen.io/kumarmasterpraveen/pen/XWNWvbm?editors=1112)

```js
let isValid = true,
    counter = 0;

const id = setInterval(() => {
  if (isValid) {
    console.log(counter++);
  }
}, 200);

setTimeout(() => {
  isValid = false;
  clearInterval(id);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: They both output integers from 0-8. Additionally, they do not "_run in a separate thread (in the background)_" - The execution of the internal operations is simply delayed, but runs synchronously. Please read about the [JavaScript event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Comment: The first code prints out 0-8 and the second code 0-9. A separate thread means not in the main thread. SetInterval code will start countdown behind the scene, so somewhere is executing code. Obviously not in the main thread, then there must be another thread.

Comment: The code executes in the main thread...the only thread. Please read the provided link. I cannot explain why in my browser they both output 0-8 - but "it works on my machine" :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm consistently seeing 0-9 in the second snippet on up-to-date Chrome on W10, what's your environment?

Comment: W10 up to date chrome

Comment: MacOS 11.1, Safari 14.0.2 - let me check Chrome.

Comment: Both are async, since the execution of both iteration at 2000 milisecond is here, so as javascript runs line by line so it is executing as first come first serve.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - How about that. Chrome produces 0-9 while Safari produces 0-8.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i think most probably this is just about execution delay nothing internal as with slight increase in timeout it prints 9 thus the delay is very tiny

Comment: Updated codepen in respective code. You could see the output difference there.

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee - can you imagine the strife this must cause developers. Will be reporting bug to Apple.

Comment: @RandyCasburn not to apple as much as the delay is less than 1 ms it is not very significant in most cases

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee - the code in your answer consistently outputs 0-8 in my environment.

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee might not be significant in this case but out there could be a case where microseconds matters

Comment: @RandyCasburn just try with  2002 or somthing with such a small increment and try to find the delay as of chrome i get 9 as output from 2001 timeout

Comment: @DeC may be but this will be surely very very rare

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee - interesting FYI - coming back to this, in my environment, I must set the `setTimeout()` delay to match the original (2000ms) + one increment time of the `setInterval()` (200ms) to achieve what you say. In other words my environment must wait an entire 2200ms before it will output 0-9 instead of 0-8.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i have tested in all environments i could and i got similar results as i stated in the answer and thus if it works on one system and the same code is delaying more on some other system then either there is something wrong with the system or maybe you are missing something out like have you tested for all values less than 2200 and have they all printed 0-8? [Although i am not sure but the delay in processing may also result due to system resources available]

Answer (score 0):

```js
let isValid = true,
    counter = 0;

setTimeout(() => {
  isValid = false;
  clearInterval(id);
}, 2001);

const id = setInterval(() => {
  if (isValid) {
    console.log(counter++);
  }
}, 200);
```

This is happening just because of delay in the execution in both cases as if we just increment the timeout just be 1 millisecond it prints 9 thus the delay is probably less than 1 millisecond to.

Well the delay may be different for different browsers.

Chrome : less than 1ms

Edge :  less than 1ms

Mozilla :

Internet Explorer: Well... The website doesn't open there